# Extract OneNote Page URL

Tags: c#, vb.net, onenote

After a long search through Dr.Google, I couldn't find how to extract a OneNote Page URL, using C# or VB.Net, to access it from a Browser. Can someone help me?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GET page API. Please refer to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/page_get

You can then use the OneNoteWebUrl from the response to access it from the browser